# python decorator methods outside of class

Tags: python, methods, decorator

Hi I am trying to get the default call to say 'nate is in the class'

I want to be able to wrap the method of a class with a default value so that the developer doesn't have to set the default value again.

but the following code give me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 18, in 
File "", line 9, in rtn
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'var1' referenced before assignment
```

I have been trying for about an hour now but I cant seem to get this to work.

Here is the code:

```
class Bob(object):

    def bob(self,var1='bob',var2=' is in the class'):
    print var1,var2


def defalter(func):
    def rtn(self=None,*args, **kwargs):
        if not var1:
            var1 = 'nate'  
    return rtn


b = Bob()

r = defalter(b.bob) 
r()
```

Comment: current code can be viewed at http://pythonfiddle.com/wrappers-and-decorators/

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Get the code above to work?

Comment: What do you want to happen if the user passes an explicit value for `var1` and/or `var2`?

Comment: to override the new default in this case 'nate' so lets say I sent in 'jane' I would want jane to be the new value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a bad idea, but the following works:

```
class Bob(object):

    def bob(self,var1='bob',var2=' is in the class'):
        print var1,var2


def defalter(func):
    func.im_func.func_defaults = ('nate',) + func.im_func.func_defaults[1:]
    return func


b = Bob()

r = defalter(b.bob) 
r()
```

I'm pretty sure that the attribute names change on python3.x, but I'm not motivated enough right now to look up what they changed to ;-).  If you know, feel free to edit.

Note that this will change that function for all `Bob`s, not just `b`.  It is unclear whether you want that or not ...

If you don't want to change it for all `Bob` instances, you can use this:

```
def defalter(func):
    def new_func(var1='nate',**kwargs):
        return func(var1=var1,**kwargs)

    return new_func
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few misunderstandings.  First, your decorator is called *before* the decorated function, so it doesn't have access to that function's local variables.  Second, even if it did, assigning new values to them would not alter the variables elsewhere.  Third, the decorator is responsible for calling the underlying function if that's what it wants to do.  Your decorator never calls the underlying function, so it can't make use of its behavior.

Here is one way to do it:

```
class Bob(object):
    def bob(self,var1='bob',var2=' is in the class'):
        print var1,var2

def defalter(func):
    def rtn(var1='nate', *args, **kwargs):
        func(var1, *args, **kwargs)
    return rtn

>>> r = defalter(b.bob)
>>> r()
nate  is in the class
```

I'm not sure why you are doing the decoration explicitly later, instead of actually decorating the method inside the class.  Also, it's not clear what you want to happen if the user passes arguments to `r`.  The way I did it basically just replaces the default value of `var1` with "nate".